# Access Resources from published application

Tags: c#, resources, embed

I embedded some .txt files in the Resources folder. When I run the project, according to selection, the .txt file name is determined.

**For example;**

The file name is sample017.txt and I keep on textName string variable. This file's full path is :

> "../../Resources\" + textName;

And I assign all of this to fileName string variable:

```
fileName = "../../Resources\\" + textName;
```

So, I use this string variable for streaming text file:

```
using (Stream input = File.OpenRead(fileName))
```

In this form, I can access to sample017.txt file and it works fine in Debugging mode.. But, when I build a setup project and install it any PC, It crashes into an Exception and it can't find the "Resources" folder. How do I manage the same using the Resources in the .exe file folder?

***Note:** I don't want to copy files to program folder. I want to embed these sources.*

Comment: Add resources folder in the setup

Comment: And have you checked that the resource folder actually exists on the target machine? Have you configured it to be deployed with the project?

Comment: @GrantThomas I don't want to replace the Resources folder to installed directory folder. I want to embed files..

Comment: @EhsanUllah how can I add resources folder to setup?

Comment: @team16sah i don't think you will be able to add text file as an embedded resource.

Comment: @EhsanUllah all of txt files are in Resources folder as embedded resource.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the ../.. from the path, because after deployment for resources is not the same as while debugging locally.

check also this thread:

[Deployed application can't find its resources c# Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857744/deployed-application-cant-find-its-resources-c-sharp-visual-studio-2010)

You could also embed your file as resource and load it using Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly. Use GetManifestResourseStream to get the content.

More details about accessing resources you find here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292

Here is a snipped..

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var res = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyNameSpace.TextFile.txt");
var textStreamReader = new StreamReader(res);
```

regards

Comment: Hi, 
Would you please give me a code snippet with details?

Thanks.

Comment: hi, sure, i added a link and a snippe. hth.